# Deprecation warning when connecting to mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm connecting to a mongoose db, and I get a deprecation warning every time I try to connect.

> (node:14933) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and
> Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future
> version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass
> option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

I set `useUnifiedTopology` to true but I'm still getting the error. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
const mongooseOptions = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
};

const dbUrl = config.get('dbUrl');

await mongoose.connect(dbUrl, mongooseOptions);
```

Comment: Looks correct to me. Does the mongo URL include any `*reconnect*` options? Could there be anywhere else a connection is made from?

Comment: @Matt your right! I'm using agenda: `const agenda = new Agenda({
 db: { address: dbUrl },
 processEvery: '1 seconds',
});` shud i be using the same connection?

Comment: Yeah, or at least [adding the same options](https://github.com/agenda/agenda/issues/1124).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DeprecationWarning` for `useUnifiedTopology` comes from the underlying [mongodb driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native). Any connections will need this setting to use the new connection management.

In agenda, pass in `options`:

```
const agenda = new Agenda({
  db: {
    address: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/agenda',
    options: {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
    }
  }
})
```

It looks like agenda can also reuse an existing mongoose connection by passing in the underlying [mongodb `db`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-db), something like:

```
const agenda = new Agenda({
  mongo: mongoose.connection.db('agenda-test')
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Which is recommended, to add the existing connection or create a new one?

Comment: The existing connection should be fine, until it's not :) Sorry hard to say as it's very specific to how hard agenda or your app hits the db and the hosting environment.